# How to send mail via sendmail path

Tags: php, email

Excuse me, I am learning to build a simple contact form on my customed website. I want to send an email via mail() but no mails are received. How do I set it via Sendmail path?

[PHP mail official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

//Email information
$to="admin@example.com";
$subject='New Form Submission';
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

//send email
mail($to,$subject,$message);

header('Location:success.html');
}

?>
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/4383900. Also try setting the FROM address

Comment: @Joshi I solved the problem via additional parameter-f. mail($to,$subject,$message, null,'-fadmin@example.com');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//send email

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,youremail@example.com);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the address you want the mail to be sent to as 'admin@example.com.' you should change it to mail($email, $subject, $message);